# Picture update without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets

I am in the process of developing a new web application. The web application includes the ability for users to create a profile page with a picture on it. I am using a regular HTML Form to allow users to input their profile information.

I would like to implement a solution where users are able to see the profile picture as soon as it is uploaded. Right now I am using jQuery File Upload (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) to upload the picture to the server and write the filename to the Database at it works fine. The problem is that the picture on the page doesn't update until the users reloads the page. I am a newbie and I am not sure what the best approach for implementing this functionality. I have done some research on AJAX calls, but I havent been able to find a guide on how to implement it in my case.

I am building my web application using Bootstrap/jQuery/JSP/Servlets/. I am not using any of the popular Java frameworks. I am a newbie with a growing knowledge of web applications.

How do I best implement a functionality that allows my profile picture to update without refreshing the page, and is there a beginner guide anywhere online?

Thank you,

Comment: You can do it this way. If upload is fine, then with AJAX on success, get back full url of image uploaded and set it to image src.

Comment: Or maybe you can use some HTML5 canvas functions for previewing the desire image to upload. Use that maybe gives the user the option to crop it and resize it before send it.

Comment: Do you have a link to a page where I can see a working implementation of a AJAX call that updates a picture?

Comment: You can use something like this: http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to troubleshoot your problem, without seeing the code you are using. Trying putting it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and giving us the link so we can better understand the problems.

The 'basic plus' version of the plugin seems to display and retrieve the image by default. There may be a small logic error that is preventing default behavior or perhaps a parameter that is missing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My issue is that I don't have any code to show at this point. I am trying to figure out how to best approach it. All I have at this point is the working jQuery File Upload on a page on its own, but it does not display the picture that i already have stored in the Database.

Comment: Ok i see, then i think @hemal solution is the cleanest and easiest. On the success callback, retrieve the url of the image and add to an 'img' attribute. 
There are optional requirements for the jQuery File Uploader, the library - [JS Image Load](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) - seems to create the image previews. for you using polyfill. This may be what you are looking for to achieve your desired result

Comment: Do you have a link to a page where I can see a working implementation of a AJAX call that updates a picture?